# wso2 data services server - cluster node and domain

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

In the DSS [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/Clustered+Deployment) describing WSO2 DSS cluster configurations, two terms are used, **Node** and **Domain**.

Am I correct in thinking that:

- **Node**: a single WSO2 DSS server?
- **Domain**: a group of one or more WSO2 DSS Nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

The WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer wiki has a lot more information on clustering.  See [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB203/Using+Load+Balancer+in+a+Cluster) for more information.